# Child process in background (ls &)

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, posix

I am making my own shell using C, if I use `&` at the end of the command then it will run in the background.. So to make it run in the background I don't use a `wait()` in the parent.

My code runs like this when I am not using `&`

```
-->ls
File1.c file2.c file.txt
-->
```

where I am printing `-->` before taking the user input for the next command.

But if I use `&` at the end, **I have just tried this with ls**

My code runs like this:

```
-->ls &
-->File1.c file2.c file.txt
```

I don't know why the `-->` symbol is not printing on the next line in this case.. Is there something with ls that executes quickly or a code issue??

I want the output to look like this when `&` is used

```
-->ls &
File1.c file2.c file.txt
-->
```

Comment: The `-->`symbol did print. And then the background process printed its output.

Comment: I need it to print after the file names

Comment: The whole point of background processes is that they work in the background, so everything they do (including printing) will be delayed. If you don't want that then don't put the process in the background.

Comment: we can not make educated remarks with out the source code.  The source code is so we can see what your code is actually doing,

Answer (score 0):

Although I have neither seen your code nor the platform you use, it seems that the processes are scheduled in a different order depending on running it in background or in foreground.

If you want to synchronize the processes, you can either establish some kind of inter-process communication or use a deterministic scheduler. The later is most certainly an overkill and infeasible.

I'd recommend to wait for the process to end or use [pipes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html).